Is DPDK 23.11 rte_flow_actions_update is applicable to i40e driver?
Need to know whether Dpdk rte_flow_actions_update has official support for intel x710 i40e NIC driver.
 struct rte_flow_action action[]={
            [0]={
             .type = RTE_FLOW_ACTION_TYPE_QUEUE,
             .conf = &queue
            },
            [1]={
            .type = RTE_FLOW_ACTION_TYPE_END,
            },
        };

I need to update the rx queue id for RTE_FLOW_ACTION_TYPE_QUEUE after creating the flow using rte_flow_actions_update.
